# Database updates

Tags: android, database, sqlite, synchronization

I can not understand how you can subscribe to database updates (SQLiteDatabase) on android?

At the moment there are several problems:

- Change from another process (if it was changed, and we use the usual observer pattern, then in our process, the update will not happen.
- Change from another instance of the class. The problem is like in the last paragraph.

I tried to use FileObserver (subscribed to the MODIFY events of the database file), but it has problems:

- One change (especially an insert) can generate more than one MODIFY event.
- In fact, he notify about EVERYONE changes in the database. In this case you need to hang some debounce, or some similar in subscribers.
- The event occurs before the database in the object is synchronized. That is, if we were notified, in the copies of the database, the data could not be updated (the state of the race).

I tried to use the FileObserver bundle -> updating the object databases -> mailing to subscribers, but for some reason in the bd the data was still not relevant.

Use the ContentProvider please do not offer, because it is implied that the changes can be obtained not only in the UI.

So, the question is: Can I somehow follow the updates of the database?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is intended to primarily be for embedded/stand-alone databases and isn't really the best solution for the typical client-server database e.g. MySQL (etc) as per :-

> SQLite is not directly comparable to client/server SQL database
> engines such as MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, or SQL Server since SQLite
> is trying to solve a different problem.
>
> Client/server SQL database engines strive to implement a shared
> repository of enterprise data. They emphasize scalability,
> concurrency, centralization, and control. SQLite strives to provide
> local data storage for individual applications and devices. SQLite
> emphasizes economy, efficiency, reliability, independence, and
> simplicity.
>
> SQLite does not compete with client/server databases. SQLite competes
> with fopen().

*extracted from [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html)*

As you have concluded, synchronising SQLite across devices is problematic, whilst server based solutions will largely eliminate the issues due to it being designed as a single source for the data, which you extract in real time.

Google's Firebase may well be a solution to the issues and is relatively well supported for Android (single SDK) and may be easier to implement than other server based solutions, again e.g MySQL.

#### In Short the answer to

> Can I somehow follow the updates of the database?

Yes you could, but it's not a 'walk in the park' in comparison to solutions designed to cope with syncronisation.

Answer (score 0):

One of solution I have found is ContentProvider which supported by Android from API 1. Unfortunatelly, it is not better solution for full-async, but in most of cases it work.